# AngularJS & Spring MVC - set templateUrl with $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application using angular js & spring-mvc.

In the header of my application

**header.jsp**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header" >
                <a class="navbar-brand"
                   href="<c:url value="/home"/>" >Pipeline Tracker
                </a >
            </div >
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li ui-sref-active="active">
                        <a ui-sref="empty">PIPELINE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li ui-sref-active="active">
                        <a ui-sref="employees">ADMIN</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**app.js**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('empty', {
        url: '/',
        view: {
            'main':{
                templateUrl: 'views/templates/empty.html',
                controller: 'EmptyController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('employees',{
        url: '/admin/employees',
        view: {
            'main':{
                templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8070/PipelineClient/views/templates/employee.jsp',
                controller: 'TestController'
            }
        }
    });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

I am unable to set the templateUrl property, so my app navigates perfectly. I can see url changing accordingly to '#/' and '#/admin/employees' but nothing is displayed. There is no error in the console also.

I tried to set templateUrl two ways. One with html and another with jsp using context url. None of them working.

I removed routing and checked the data loads pefectly. No issue with data loading.

**for loading dependencies:**

```
var app = angular.module('pipeline', [
    'ngResource',
    'infinite-scroll',
    'angularSpinner',
    'jcs-autoValidate',
    'angular-ladda',
    'mgcrea.ngStrap',
    'toaster',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.router'
]);
```

**index.jsp**

```
<div class="container main-content">
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Directory Structure:]

How to set this templateUrl property? I am relatively new to angular, so do let know if you need any more info on this.

Comment: does it work if you view the page directly without using the buttons? ex: http://localhost:8070/#/admin/employees

Comment: is it working when you go to state `empty`?

Comment: @vidalsasoon: no even the direct url access isn't working

Comment: @ShaohaoLin: No, it isn't working for any of the states..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a syntax error, should be "views" and not "view".

```
.state('employees',{
        url: '/admin/employees',
        views: { <--- change view to views
            'main':{
                templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8070/PipelineClient/views/templates/employee.jsp',
                controller: 'TestController'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes.. That was the mistake... i changed it to views and it started working :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the "view:" syntax you're using. does it work if you do:

```
    .state("test", {
        templateUrl: "views/templates/empty.html",
        controller: 'EmptyController'
        }
```

http://localhost:8070/#/test

Comment: Your ans was correct.. but as @jawche pointed out, it was a syntax error.